# How to safely preserve html color with angularjs sanitize

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ngsanitize

After use `$sanitize` to my `ng-html-bind`, all style was removed. But using `$sce.trustAsHtml` cause secure issue.

So, is there any way to preserve color after `$sanitize`?

For Example,

**Original string**

`<p><span style="color: rgb(65, 140, 175);">blue</span></p>`

**After $sanitize**

`<p><span>blue</span></p>`

The color is also auto removed by stackoverflow, for the example below:

blue

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue.  trumbowyg formats color as with the OP's example.  I'm trying to display that content read-only, and the color is gone.  I hope I can figure out a solution without using trustAsHtml, but I doubt it.